# Как сравнить массив с базой данных и вернуть булевое значение?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы

У меня на входе есть массив с неуникальными значениями. Мне нужно сравнить этот масив на предмет наличия соответствия значения из массива любой строке в таблице и вернуть false, если соответствие не найдено или true, если значение найдено, то есть если массив имеет 10 элементов, то и в ответе от базы я должен получить 10 элементов. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: В базе находятся таблицы, а в таблицах - строки. Также можно поглядеть в сторону `WHERE field IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: left join `(select 1 x union select 2 union select 3 ....) x` с таблицей и потом group by до x.x и в качестве признака использовать например max() от поля таблицы

Comment: напиши еще пример данных массива и пример одной строчки в базе